# Is it possible to use a table from another database?

Tags: mysql, database, google-cloud-sql

I would like to know if it is possible to see and use a table in a database(Local MySQL), which is stored in another database remotely(Google cloud SQL).

I need this because our website needs to run of a localhost MySQL database for speed and we have a google cloud hosted server for our game/server.
But we do not want to have to copy or duplicate the users table every so often, or do all actions regarding users on both tables.

Like I said earlier we can't use the google one because it increases page load by at least 2 times( normaly page loads in a second, with google 2-5 seconds)

Comment: what exactly do you mean? keep separate data for separate applications, but access both databases? just do that. use your local database to join the cloud-DB? then *there* will be the same delay. keep a local replica without actually replicating your cloud-DB? impossible by definition.  - please try to be more clear about what you actually are trying to *achieve*

Comment: I think you can create multiple database connection object and use which you want to use. example 1 for local and other for remote database.

Comment: The kind of table you want is called *federated*  . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-create-server.html

Comment: We want to use one table in both databases without having duplicated data and such.

Comment: @O.Jones Does that federated table only save data to one server or still to both but synced, I can't seem to get that out of the page.

Comment: "The FEDERATED storage engine lets you access data from a remote MySQL database without using replication or cluster technology. Querying a local FEDERATED table automatically pulls the data from the remote (federated) tables. No data is stored on the local tables." says the documentation.

Comment: I have tried the federated engine, sadly it is not enabled for our shared hosting account and can not be enabled.
Any other options?